# Not able to run a feature file in protractor-cucumber

Tags: protractor

While I am giving 'cucumber-js' command in order to run a feature file in Windows 8, it shows following error:

> cucumber-js' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error tells you the computer can't find cucumber-js.exe or cucumber-js.cmd or cucumber-js.bat from current folder(where you type the cucumber-js in cmd window) and PATH enviroment variable.

**Option 1):**  install cucumber as a NPM global package by executing `npm install -g cucumber`

then append NPM global package install folder path into PATH environment variable.

(To know where is NPM global package install folder, you can execute  `npm config get prefix`  in cmd window, it should print out a folder path, that's it)

**Option 2):** install cucumber as project local package by executing `npm install cucumber` after switch into your project folder in cmd window.

then you will find node_modules\.bin\cucumber-js.cmd start from project folder, so give cucumber as  `node_modules\.bin\cucumber-js`